# How can I Mock HttpRequest[] indexer property

Tags: c#, moq, httprequest, xunit

I'm adding unit tests to a large legacy codebase written in C#/ASP.NET/webforms.  We are using MOQ and XUnit.  We've been able to mock query string values using syntax like:

```
Mock<HttpRequestBase> request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
NameValueCollection queryStringParams = new NameValueCollection();
queryStringParams.Add("name", "Fred Jones");
request.Setup(x => x.QueryString).Returns(queryStringParams);
```

That allows this code to work fine:

```
string name = _mockRequest.QueryString["name"];
```

The problem is that sprinkled throughout the codebase are many calls to get query string variables or form variables in the form of:

```
string name = HttpContext.Current.Request["name"];
```

The indexer apparently looks in all the various collections: query strings, form values, cookies, and server variables.  I don't want to introduce a lot of potential side effects by refactoring the production code to use a single one of these collections.

Does anyone know a way to mock that indexer on the HttpRequest?

Comment: WebForms or MVC? With MVC you can set `controller.ControllerContext`

Comment: Take a look on the mvc-contrib test helpers. it does it for you out of the box.

Comment: This link may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1214233/220061

Comment: Yes, we are doing the mocking of the context and request as that post recommends.  It's this one specific indexer that's giving us issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured this one out, it was simpler than I was making it.

```
//
// Set a variable in the indexer collction
//
Mock<HttpRequestBase> request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
request.SetupGet(r => r["name"]).Returns("Fred Jones");
```