# Moq item from session

Tags: c#, moq

How can I moq the following so it returns a new Guid();

```
private void CheckSomething(){
...
    user = CustomerContext.Current.User; // returns Guid
```

CustomerContext is taken from a third party library and it is not injected into my class.

is there any way to do it?

Comment: You must create a wrapper of that third party library.

Comment: Sounds like it should be injected into the class so it can be mocked.  (Possibly wrapped in an interface, depending on how mockable it is.)  Basically, your unit testing is indicating to you that the code is coupled to a dependency.  That should be corrected.

Comment: how do I create a wrapper?

Comment: @ShaneKm: A class with pass-through operations to the 3rd party object should do the trick.  Have that class implement an interface, then use that interface to create mocks.  The code being tested should rely on the interface (wrapper), not on the 3rd party object.

Comment: But this would require me to modify the method tested so that instead of user = CustomerContext => I would change it to CustomerContextWrapper.Current.User. Correct? I don't really want to modify existing code in that method. Is that the only option?

Comment: @ShaneKm I believe that is the only option.  Writing testable code requires a certain amount of planning up front - loose coupling, DI, not relying so heavily on static methods, etc.  Without that initial planning/implementation up front, you'll likely have to do some refactoring.

Comment: @ShaneKm related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214178/moq-unit-testing-a-method-relying-on-httpcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this.

```
public class UserContextWrapper : ICustomUserContext
{
    public Guid UserGuid
    {
        get { return CustomerContext.Current.User; }
    }
}
```

Then In my code I had to modify original to:

```
private void CheckSomething(){
...
    user = UserContextWrapper.UserGuid ; // returns Guid
```

Now I'm able to mock. I'm simply injecting ICustomerUserContext into my class and I have mapped UserContextWrapper to ICustomUserContext in IoC Container.

Comment: how are you providing your implementation to `UserContextWrapper` from your class?