# Possibility mock httpcontext.current.profile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Is it possible to mock

HttpContext.Current.Profile

Currently i have to test(UnitTest) an actionresult which uses profile.
please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moq: unit testing a method relying on HttpContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214178/moq-unit-testing-a-method-relying-on-httpcontext)