# HttpRequest unit testing mock IP and Browser

Tags: .net, unit-testing, httprequest

I've written two extension methods for getting IP / Browser from current HttpRequest:

```
public static class Extensions
{    
    public static string IP (this HttpRequest currentRequest)
    {
        string ips = currentRequest.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ips))
        {
            return ips.Split(',')[0];
        }
        return currentRequest.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    public static string Browser (this HttpRequest currentRequest)
    {
        return currentRequest.Browser.Type;
    }
}
```

I would like to unit test both methods. I've seen answers how to mock http request like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214178/moq-unit-testing-a-method-relying-on-httpcontext). But I can not mock IP and Browser from HttpRequest. Any ideas ?

Comment: How about first mocking HttpRequest, and then just request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] = "fake ip"? But in general, don't use static methods if you want this part of functionality to be testable with unit tests.

Comment: Given that all dependencies are passed in and no dependency is made on other static classes, this is still nice and testable.

Comment: @Evk - I've tried your solution and it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work how exactly?

Comment: The exception is thrown: System.PlatformNotSupportedException - Operation is not supported on this platform. It is thrown immediately after sentence: request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] = "fake ip"